# Paypal IPN payment_status says completed but payment was declined

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using Paypal Rest API PHP and IPN. I am testing paypal live with a buyer and seller account. I have tried a buyer with not enough balance. After executing the payment, the payment did not push through since it has not enough balance but **$_POST['payment_status']** returned '*Completed*'. I want to detect via IPN that my payment was successful or not. So i am using **$_POST['payment_status']** to trigger that so i could update my database on my site. Why is it returning *Completed* even if my payment was declined? Do you think $_POST['payment_status'] is not what i need? please help

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bug. I would advise you create a support ticket and provide the following information:-
1. sample of IPN message you received
2. correlation/debug id
3. timestamp

Below is the url to submit the support ticket to PayPal MTS:-
https://www.paypal-techsupport.com

Regards, 
Giovani